# Javascript hide button that using history.go(-1) when it's disabled

Tags: javascript, back, history.js

I have created a button in my app that acts like the the browser back button. I used :

```
 window.history.go(-1)
```

It works fine but when it's disabled (in the toolbar of the browser so also in my page because they have the same component) I would like to hide my app back button too.

It's disabled for example when a new window is opened. So when on this new window, I would like that the back button I created is hidden. The button I created is in a `div`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test if history has a length greater than 1 (one is the current page), and hide your button if not one page load

```
if(window.history.length <= 1)
    document.getElementById("button").style.display = "none";
```